# How to log a user in by getting data from an API?

Tags: django

I am writing an API view where am accessing API to POST email and password to the address and fetch response.So i want if response is 200 or repose message is 'Success' then to login with available email and password datas, but i'm not able to do so. How to achieve such?

```
class ApiLoginView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'


    def post(self,request):
        email = request.POST.get('login-email')
        print(email)

        password = request.POST.get('login-password')
        print(password)
        API_KEY = '*********************'
        API_URL = 'http://devstudio.com/rest/storeLogin'
        parameter = {
            'authToken':API_KEY,
            'email':email,
            'password':password,
        }
        r = session.post(url = API_URL, params=parameter)
        return HttpResponse(r)
```

Comment: Please define "login with available email and password datas" ("login" where ???) and "i'm not able to do so".

Answer (score 0):

if you are using djagno's built-in auth and user system then you can use something like this

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
class ApiLoginView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'index.html'


def post(self,request):
    email = request.POST.get('login-email')
    print(email)

    password = request.POST.get('login-password')
    print(password)
    API_KEY = '*********************'
    API_URL = 'http://devstudio.com/rest/storeLogin'
    parameter = {
        'authToken':API_KEY,
        'email':email,
        'password':password,
    }
    r = session.post(url = API_URL, params=parameter)
    if r.status_code==200:
       user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
       if user is not None:
          login(request, user)
          # Redirect to a success page.

       else:
         # Return an 'invalid login' error message.


    return HttpResponse(r)
```

for reference check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization
hope this helps..

Comment: hi thanks for commenting, i have tried this using default auth of django,it works but can you tell me how to do this with api call? how to authenticate then?

Comment: sorry, but I didn't quite get your comment what do you mean by API call which API are you talking about

Comment: i mean how to do such login with out using django auth and user system?

Comment: are you using custom authentication?

Comment: right now using none, i use api to know its valid data or not through its response..

Comment: so after getting the response from your API, you can skip the call to authenticate and log in the user directly with login(request, user)

Comment: can i use session to login?

Comment: depends on how your build your auth system